# Are copies of the Temple's keilim assur behanaah?

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, yoreh-deah, masecheth-avodah-zarah, issurei-hanaa

The Talmud in [Masechet Avodah Zarah 43a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.43a.14) states Jews are forbidden from making replicas of items of the Temple.

My question is: once a replica has been created, is it prohibited to derive any benefit from it (i.e. is there an issur hanaah)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SA [YD 141:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.141.8?lang=bi&with=Pitchei%20Teshuva) says that one cannot make a replica of the keilim in the mikdash:

> לא יעשה בית תבנית היכל כשיעור גבהו וארכו ורחבו אכסדרה תבנית אולם. חצר תבנית עזרה. שלחן תבנית שלחן מנורה תבנית מנורה

The Pischei Teshuva says there that if a non-jew makes it, one may use it (obviously, as long as they don’t own it):

> לא יעשה. עי' בספר תפארת למשה שכתב דאם עובד כוכבים עשאה לו מותר לדור בבית ולהשתמש במנורה ושולחן ע"ש

Comment: "as long as they don’t own it" this doesn't appear in your quotation